# phalcon: what is the role of "--force" in the scaffold command?

Tags: command-line, scaffold, phalcon

When we use this command (for example);

> phalcon scaffold products --force

what is the benefit of "--force"? Please explain for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option overwrites any modified file generated before by the same command, if you run the scaffold passing this option, you'll lose any changes, however the new generated scaffold will generate the files with fields added/modified/dropped in the table.